# Automate data flow from MS Access to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, vba, ms-access, pdo

I need to automate a data flow from MS-Access to MySQL for an insurance company.
Users will continue to work in MS-Access, but the changes done through the Access forms should take effect in MySQL as well.
This is the decision of our web analyst, because the web system will not be able to replace all MS-Access functionalities that are currently used, and the data management will currently continue to be done in MS-Access (this was the decision).

I see two options, and one of the options contains my question:

- Automate the data upload through VBA (when changes occur via the form, an Ajax request sends the data via GET parameters to a PHP script on the server that performs the necessary manipulations on the data before storing them in MySQL. Immediate upload into MySQL could have been possible as well, but it was decided not to do this);
- Send a simple request to a PHP script, and perform all actions in PHP: Get records from MS-Access in PHP, manipulate the data in PHP, and store them to MySQL in PHP. (My preference. I will need to create a script that runs automatic migrations every night as well, so I will need to do this anyway).

The MS-Access database is stored on our local network, ie. a different server than where the PHP script runs (which is an external web server).
I would prefer to manage everything in PHP, but (my question):

> Is it possible to connect to the host of our local network and the
>   host of the external server simultaneously, querying data from
>   MS-Access, manipulating them with PHP and inserting / updating them in MySQL at the
>   same time, in a single script?

Comment: Can you not bind the tables to Access and use the MySQL tables instead of the Access tables?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not always a 1-1 connection, so I need intermediary scripts to manipulate the data. The reason why the flow was decided from MS Access to MySQL is because the commercial representatives and actuary currently use the MS Access tool and it would take some time to create interfaces for managing all the data in MySQL, while the development of the accounting system has received absolute priority.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, if I get your question right, but it is possible to attach a mysql database via odbc to an access-frontend. that way you could work with access without having an access-backend.

Comment: Yeah, you don't need an access back-end at all but if you do, you can just alter the access forms to run a SQL query when information is changed. ADODB Connections are your friend!

Comment: We actually need the Access back end. The trouble here is that not all changes will need instant syncing - only a few (when instantly needed for running an accounting for example). For a set of updates, the sync will be run at night; so actually I still need a way to get the data from Access to move it to MySQL in a single script. One reason I prefer not to do this in VBA is because I don't trust that it will be reliable for the mass of data that I need to sync.

Comment: @JonBlumfeld The trouble is that there are really a whole lot of forms and data - changing all these forms would require a lot of development time. Not all data will require instant upload, so for the majority of the data, the streamline between MS Access and MySQL will be done through a single script that manages all the syncing at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to connect to the host of our local network and the
>   host of the external server simultaneously, querying data from
>   MS-Access, manipulating them with PHP and inserting / updating them in
>   MySQL at the same time, in a single script?

Yes, but you don't really need a PHP script, access can work with MySQL through an ODBC connection or by using ADODB connections. It would be easiest to modify the forms to work with the MYSQL back-end.

The advantage of the ODBC connection is you can insert from the access DB to the MySQL DB in a single query.
Using ADODB connections you can take an access query, and do a batch insert (you'll have to do it through a string), but that can also be relatively quick since you only connect to the MySQL db to send the INSERT command, the rest is string manipulation.

If you are going to go with an asynchronous bulk update through php

```
<?php
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "products\products.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
```

That code will allow you to connect to the access back-end (credit to http://www.sitepoint.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/)
note that the queries will be parsed by access, so you should format them the access way.

Comment: Thanks, but as my last comment mentions; not all changes will require instant syncing. The Access tool is huge (insurance stuff you know) and adapting the VBA code for all data changes would require too much expensive development time. Therefore, the sync is run at night (bulk) - which is something I would not trust in VBA. Although theoretically possible, I would see the Access-VBA code to get stuck at certain points with a massive amount of data - I guess that a pure PHP solution would be more reliable.

Comment: either one could get stuck with massive amounts of data. but php can connect to an mdb I will update my answer with some helpful code

Comment: Thanks @serakfalcon. Btw, my question explicitly handles about two active db connections at two different servers simultaneously, performing PDO executions in a single script.

Comment: having the two different connections isn't a problem, just don't mix the variables up is all.

Comment: Thanks, so it's possible to do it in a single script - exactly what I wasn't so certain of.